# Get selected text from current window with C++ \ Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm trying to get selected text from active window of another app in my Qt application.
On Linux I just use `QClipboard` in `Selection` mode.
On Windows I'm trying to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to system:

```
INPUT copyText;
copyText.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
copyText.ki.wScan = 0;
copyText.ki.time = 0;
copyText.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

Sleep(200);
// Press the "Ctrl" key
copyText.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
copyText.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &copyText, sizeof(INPUT));

// Press the "C" key
copyText.ki.wVk = 'C';
copyText.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &copyText, sizeof(INPUT));

Sleep(50);

// Release the "C" key
copyText.ki.wVk = 'C';
copyText.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &copyText, sizeof(INPUT));

// Release the "Ctrl" key
copyText.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
copyText.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &copyText, sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(50);
```

But this hack doesn't work properly - sometimes I don't get selection. I think it can be caused by a hot key that calls function with this code and some keys are still pressed while this code is running. How can I check if every key isn't pressed from QKeySequenceEdit? Or how can I check if no one key pressed?
Or is there an easier way to get the selected text from the active window on Windows?

Comment: Why do not you keep using QClipBoard for windows?

Comment: Calling `SendInput()` with `nInputs=1` is (almost always) a mistake. That defeats the purpose of using `SendInput()` instead of `keybd_event()`. Create an array of multiple `INPUT`s and pass the whole array to `SendInput()` at one time with `nInputs` set to the number of `INPUT`s in the array. And get rid of the `Sleep()` calls, they are not needed. If you need to check if a given key is already down, use `GetAsyncKeyState()`. Alternatively, try using `GetGUIThreadInfo()` to get the `HWND` that currently has input focus and then send it a `WM_COPY` message.

Comment: Or, if the `HWND` is a standard Edit control, you can use a combination of `EM_GETSEL` and `WM_GETTEXT` to extract the selected text without going through the clipboard. Or, if the `HWND` is a standard RichEdit control, use a combination of `EM_EXGETSEL` and `EM_GETSELTEXT`.  Or, use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead.

Comment: @eyllanesc, because QClipboard don't work on Windows in Selection mode. @RemyLebeau, thanks for explanation! Which solution will be more universal to get selection from any app, send `Ctrl + C` or send a `WM_COPY` message?

Comment: @ГенаЧерныщук So, why do you use the Qt tag?

Comment: @eyllanesc, because I don't know how to check with `GetAsyncKeyState()` if any button pressed from `QKeySequenceEdit`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Hmm... Sending shortcut with GetAsyncKeyState() looks like more universal solution for any app. But how I can get keys for GetAsyncKeyState() from QKeySequenceEdit?

Comment: [`QKeySequenceEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html) has a [`QKeySequence`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html) which you can enumerate to get individual keys. Translate each key from a [Qt key code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) to a [Windows virtual key code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx) to use when querying [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx) and sending with [`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, but how I can translate Qt key code into Windows virtual key code?

Comment: @Shatur95 create your own lookup table to map one to the other

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you! I got it! But this method of obtaining the selected text has the disadvantage - previous clipboard is lost. I tried to save clipboard data to `QMimeType` before sending `Ctrl + C` and restore after sending, but it works strange: when I restoring clipboard data I sometimes don't get selected text (I get the clipboard that was before sending `Ctrl + C`), but without restoring clipboard data everything work properly. Why could this happen? Is QClipboard works asynchronously?

Comment: @Shatur95: Not everything in a UI responds to `Ctrl+C` by copying something to the clipboard (and yes, copying is asynchronous, since [keypress handling is asynchronous](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773/), so generation of `WM_COPY` messages can be delayed). That is why I mentioned several alternatives that don't rely on using the Clipboard at all. Otherwise, you might consider monitoring the Clipboard for real-time changes via `AddClipboardFormatListener()` or `SetClipboardViewer()`, and then act on the Clipboard only if `Ctrl+C` actually causes a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to get selected text:

```
QString MainWindow::selectedText()
{
    QString selectedText;
#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
    selectedText = QApplication::clipboard()->text(QClipboard::Selection);
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN) // Send Ctrl + C to get selected text
    // Save original clipboard data
    QVariant originalClipboard;
    if (QApplication::clipboard()->mimeData()->hasImage())
        originalClipboard = QApplication::clipboard()->image();
    else
        originalClipboard = QApplication::clipboard()->text();

    // Wait until the hot key is pressed
    while (GetAsyncKeyState(translateSelectedHotkey->currentNativeShortcut().key) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)
           || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
        Sleep(50);

    // Generate key sequence
    INPUT copyText[4];

    // Set the press of the "Ctrl" key
    copyText[0].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    copyText[0].ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    copyText[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    // Set the press of the "C" key
    copyText[1].ki.wVk = 'C';
    copyText[1].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    copyText[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    // Set the release of the "C" key
    copyText[2].ki.wVk = 'C';
    copyText[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    copyText[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    // Set the release of the "Ctrl" key
    copyText[3].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    copyText[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    copyText[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    // Send key sequence to system
    SendInput(4, copyText, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Wait for the clipboard to change
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer timer; // Add a timer for the case where the text is not selected
    loop.connect(QApplication::clipboard(), &QClipboard::changed, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    timer.start(1000);
    loop.exec();

    // Translate the text from the clipboard if the selected text was not copied
    if (timer.isActive())
        return QApplication::clipboard()->text();
    else
        timer.stop();

    // Get clipboard data
    selectedText = QApplication::clipboard()->text();

    // Return original clipboard
    if (originalClipboard.type() == QVariant::Image)
        QApplication::clipboard()->setImage(originalClipboard.value<QImage>());
    else
        QApplication::clipboard()->setText(originalClipboard.toString());
#endif
    return selectedText;
}
```

To set global shortcuts I used [QHotkey](https://github.com/Skycoder42/QHotkey). From QHotkey I get native keycodes using the `currentNativeShortcut().key` method.